# How to obtain the id of an item which the mongo db is currently displaying

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I use meteor for my project and I have the following code:

```
<div class="col-md-4 activities_text">
        <center><h2>Learn</h2><br/><br/></center>
        {{getContent.description}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="button_absolute">
        <button class="button_ahead"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
        </div>
        <img class="activities_image" name="image" src="{{getContent.src}}"/>
        </div>
        </div>
```

And I want to obtain the id or (subsequently the whole information in the database) about the item which my HTML currently uses for the "src" of the image subsequently for title and description. So I could swap them when the button is clicked. I tried this:

```
 'click .button_ahead':function(event){
      var infoNumber = this.number;
      console.log("this is the number of the image"+this._id+" "+ this.number);
      infoNumber = infoNumber + 1;
      Session.set("number", infoNumber);
    }
```

but both this.number and this._id remain undefined. Maybe the problem is that when I click the button I should obtain the data about the image etc.. but not for the button itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context is the button element, so, `this` is probably not what you want to use, if you really want to use `this` try changing the context with `.call()` or `.apply()` functions.

---

*PS: I'd like to leave a comment under question but I can't due to the rep points*

Comment: I suggest you to use the developer console to debug and check the variables on the current scope and context (and the value of `this`)

Answer (score 0):

`$(event.currentTarget)[0].id` would give you the id of the button in

```
'click .button_ahead':function(event){
      var id = $(event.currentTarget)[0].id
      var infoNumber = this.number;
      console.log("this is the number of the image"+id+" "+ this.number);
      infoNumber = infoNumber + 1;
      Session.set("number", infoNumber);
    }
```

so in your template you can simply put

```
<button class="button_ahead" id="this._id"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
```

to get the id of the current resource you're displaying.

you can also use more simply `event.currentTarget.id`